# Control variable in add member variable wizard is disabled. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, wizard

I have a MFC dialog derived from CMyDialog (is a CDialog) and try to add a control with the "add member variable wizard". But the checkbox "control variable" is grayed out. Any ideas what the problem is?

For example: 
I have a edit control and want to add a int variable with lower and upper border (min and max value). I need to check "control variable" and set "catagory" to value. But "control variable" is grayed out.

I tried also button or list control, but "control variable" is grayed out.

Comment: For what kind of control do you want to add a member variable?

Comment: Do you right-click on a control and select member var or do you just click inside the dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add a control variable using the wizard, **you must have an `IDD` enum defined in the class header and use this in the constructor**. For example:

Header:

```
class CMyDialog : public CDialog 
{
public:
  // Dialog Data
  enum { IDD = IDD_MYDIALOG };
  ⋮
};
```

Source:

```
CMyDialog::CMyDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
  : CDialog(CMyDialog::IDD, pParent)
{
    ⋮
}
```

On the other hand, if you use the resource ID directly in the constructor's initialization list (instead of using the `IDD` enum in the header), then you can't add a member variable or use the "control variable" checkbox in the IDE.

Source:

```
CMyDialog::CMyDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
  : CDialog(IDD_MYDIALOG, pParent)
{
    ⋮
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some bug in VS2008. I faced similar issue once.

Try adding a control and double click it. You'll have an handler generated. Then click on the control and add control variable.

This worked for me.

Comment: works not for me, but i have found the solution for my problem, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem here, but due to performance reasons we had disabled the Intellisense update ('Disable Database Auto Updates = true'). I suppose the MFC wizzard uses Intellisense. Just re-enable it or rescan your solution and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas Belke is right. We were facing the same issue. Also note that if you have a `typedef` for your dialog class somewhere, you will have the same problem.

The following example does not work (VS2015):

```
typedef CDialog         CBaseDialog;

class CMyDialog : public CBaseDialog
{
public:
  // Dialog Data
  enum { IDD = IDD_MYDIALOG };
  ⋮
};

CMyDialog::CMyDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
  : CBaseDialog(IDD_MYDIALOG, pParent)
{
    ⋮
}
```